Initialize a integral variable to +/- infty for a running min/max in Haskell
In running minimum/maximum problems, the e.g. minimum-so-far is often initialized to \infty in order to guarantee we "capture" every minimum, no matter where it is located.
In Haskell, we have minBound and maxBound for Int, but these don't behave as we would like because if we do arithmetic "locally" near these bounds, they may under/overflow. For Integer we have nothing. Obviously we could use something like Float, but using a fractional type for an integral problem merely to make use of these infinite values seems like overkill.
It is also possible to translate the problem to something that requires a nonempty input, but this is not very nice because it often makes case analysis much more complex, and also because in situations where you are taking the running minimum/maximum of some fixed-size window, you need an entire window of elements, not just a singleton.
My question is, how can we solve running min/max problems using Integer without requiring nonempty inputs, or is it impossible?

You can always freely adjoin a global minimum/maximum using Maybe.

Addendum: using Rational and infinity from GHC.Real may be a nice solution if you can get over using a fractional type. Since Ratio Integer is infinite-precision, it should behave very much like Integer except if you need to call functions that specifically take/return Int/Integer, in which case you'll need some fromIntegrals sprinkled in.

You might like monoid-extras' Inf type.

You could work with a Maybe (Max a). Indeed, we can then use the Monoid instance [Hackage] of this, and thus fold the collection of elements, since:
ghci> Nothing <> Just (Max 12)
Just (Max {getMax = 12})
ghci> Nothing <> Just (Max 25)
Just (Max {getMax = 25})
ghci> Just (Max 14) <> Just (Max 25)
Just (Max {getMax = 25})
ghci> Just (Max 14) <> Nothing
Just (Max {getMax = 14})
ghci> Nothing <> (Nothing :: Maybe (Max Integer))
Nothing

here we thus use Nothing like you can use (negative) infinity for (maximum)/minimum.
We thus can for a list of elements wrap the items into a Just (Max …), for example:
ghci> foldMap (Just . Max) [1,4,2,5]
Just (Max {getMax = 5})
ghci> foldMap (Just . Max) []
Nothing


It's nice but I'm not sure it really gets around the problem of needing to do extra case analysis. The nice thing about using an infinite value in other languages is that you can do ordinary arithmetic with it. The possibility of a Nothing here means we either have to handle infinity separately, or use fmap/<*> in our arithmetic. This is what I meant by "makes case analysis much more complex".

I think if this is the best we can do, it might be preferable to simply initialize to a very large magnitude value.

@lanf: well a lot of programming languages don't have native support for something like an Integer: in Java there is the BigInteger which also has no infinity, and was, until the introduction of overridable operators, quite painful to work with. I think the advantage of the Maybe ... is that it will work for anything that is a Semigroup. So if we don't know if we will get an Integer, Int, or String. But yes, it produces a lot of "unpacking" and "repacking".

@willeM_VanOnsem What do you mean, "was" until the introduction of overridable operators? To this day Java still doesn't support those, and BigInteger still sucks to work with.

@amalloy: I think I got confused, some tools like manifold allow to rewrite the Java code: https://debugagent.com/operator-overloading-in-java so a + b is then rewritten to a.plus(b), or something similar.

@lanf "The nice thing about using an infinite value in other languages" -- what infinite value, in what language?

@DanielWagner e.g. float("inf") in python.

@Ianf: but that is for a Float, for a Float, in Haskell you have 1/0 for example.

@lanf You explicitly called out floating point numbers as "overkill" in the question...! If floating point is fine, you can read "Infinity" :: Float in Haskell for the same effect.

I did indeed, apologies. But I think an important distinction is to be made here. If you do arithmetic on integers and make comparisons with a float("inf"), your arithmetic will be integer arithmetic and you will not lose precision. It does not appear as though we can achieve the same behavior in Haskell.

@lanf It is of course achievable. Though I admit it is likely not available from any standard library.

For running min/max problems, you can use scanl1. It is not partial.
> scanl1 max [3, 2, 5]
[3,3,5]
> scanl1 max []
[]

You can use this to build just the final answer if you like, using your favorite variant of last, including both partial variants and total variants that require additional pattern matching.
